# Comparing date ranges between different length vectors in R

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am having a little bit of trouble with the below example and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have two vectors **x** and **y**.  **x** is a vector of length 78,725 which contains a date range from `"2017-04-23 06:55:00 UTC" to "2017-04-27 17:00:52 UTC"` but the interval of time between each element differs from 1 second to a couple of hours.  **y** is a vector of length 8640 which contains a date range from `"2017-04-23 00:00:00 UTC" to "2017-04-23 23:59:50 UTC"` in increments of 10 seconds.  I would like to identify which `x >= y and x < y`

**SAMPLE DATA**:

```
x <- as.POSIXct(c("2017-04-24 18:32:35", "2017-04-24 14:01:03", "2017-04-24 17:51:35",
                  "2017-04-24 15:42:22", "2017-04-24 13:00:51", "2017-04-24 16:56:28",
                  "2017-04-24 17:17:32", "2017-04-24 15:03:34", "2017-04-24 22:40:47",
                  "2017-04-23 17:37:15"), tz = "UTC")
base.date <- as.POSIXct("2017-04-23 0:00:00", tz = "UTC")
every = 10
seconds.in.day = 60*60*24
y <- seq(base.date, length = seconds.in.day / every, by = every)
```

**RESULTS I WANT**:

The 10th position of x i.e. `"2017-04-23 17:37:15 UTC"` is between y element 6344 and 6345.

**TRIED THE FOLLOWING**:

```
mapply(function(x, y) x >= y & x < y, as.data.frame(x), as.data.frame(y))
```

and

```
Position(function(x) x >= y & x < y, x)
```

and

```
vapply(x, function(x) x >= y & x < y, logical(NROW(x)))
```

None of these have returned what I am wanting

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please provide a reproducible example of the data and the desired output.

Comment: its been reposted

Answer (score 0):

You sample data is difficult because only one of the observations in `x` falls within the range of `y`. So I've written the following to account for that. Give this a try...

```
# Filter down only to observations within the date range of y
 x_range <- x[max(y) >= x & min(y) <= x]

 for (i in length(x_range)) {
   upper.y.index <- vector('numeric')
   upper.y.index[i] <- which.max(y < x_range[i])

   lower.y.index <- vector('numeric')
   lower.y.index[i] <- which.max(y >= x_range[i])
 }


 upper.y.index
 [1] 1
 lower.y.index
 [1] 6345
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark but I made a slight modification to your suggestion in order to avoid a for loop `lower.y.index <- sapply(x_range, function(x) which.min(y <= x) - 1)` `upper.y.index <- sapply(x_range, function(x) which.max(y > x))` `y[lower.y.index]` `y[upper.y.index]`